# Inlie series of IFs present The truth value of a Series is ambiguous Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to add and fill a column in a `Pandas` `DataFrame` based on a series of if conditions.
My code looks like this

`df['E'] = (('Text1;' if df['A'] else '') + ('Text2;' if df['B'] else '')) +  ('Text3;' if df['C'] else '')`

The dataframe looks like

```
A       B        C        D
TRUE    FALSE    FALSE    4
FALSE   TRUE     TRUE     7
FALSE   FALSE    FALSE    1
```

compiler errors out saying Truth Value being Ambiguous, I tried playing with parenthesis as suggested by SO but cant get this to work.

I have checked many other threads on SO around this error but none point to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: you check many threads you see np.where? np.select? what you write with it? or did you try matrix multiplcation thing for this

Comment: thanks for the comment @athing, I checked the ones i searched and I couldnt figure out how to concatinate string based on multiple ifs in np.select

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my approach ?

Comment: It would also help if you add your dataframe so that others can reproduce the error

Comment: Truth Value being Ambiguous is whats wrong with your way, there are many many answers why its wrong. and some suggest np.select etc. I thought in worst case you write 8=2^3 possiblities in np.select after you "check many therads". Theres a matrix multiplcation way let me try wrting an answer

Comment: @athing do you believe there are only 3 ifs and hence just 2^3 options ? surely my question looks little simplified than the actual case ?

Comment: Does your dataframe really look like this? Because with all caps TRUE and FALSE they are certainly not booleans...

Comment: Muds your line of code reads natural but not how pandas or numpy works with ifs, it has vectorization rather. so one way is to put all possible conditions in np.select but it is 2^3 here. another way is matrix multiplication for your case and i write answer for it maybe helps maybe not.

Comment: `df['A']` is a Series with a value `[True, False, False]`. You cannot find the truth value of a series or a DataFrame. Same goes for other columns.

Comment: @mcsoini -- superb observation -- these column values are set in previous statements by setting them as this --

`df['A'] = df['D'] >= min_val` -- when I print this df, it prints in All Upper case 

First few days with py hence struggling with basics!

Comment: @mcsoini pd.read_clipboard fixes that for you

Comment: @athing I get that, but if they are "TRUE"/"FALSE" strings in the OP's data, you certainly don't want pd.read_clipboard to "fix" it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way not working because: if else with series and dfs are not good and there are many many QAs why it is wrong and what to do.

but still you could try `np.select` with 2^3 possibilities after checking them but you didn't show such attempt.

theres another way with matrix mul:

```
#pd.Index plays better than list when it comes to @ below
texts = pd.Index(["Text1;", "Text2;","Text3;"])
#choose interested columns
columns = ["A","B","C"]
#perform matrix mult and assign
df["E"] = df[columns] @ texts
```

matrix multiplication here with @ is "sum of products". It produces 3 such sum, one is for example `"Text1;" * True + "Text2;" * False + "Text3;" * False` for the first E result. this is usual matrix multiplcation as you might know

df becomes

```
       A      B      C  D             E
0   True  False  False  4        Text1;
1  False   True   True  7  Text2;Text3;
2  False  False  False  1
```

2^3 way with np.select. we form "logic table" from 000 to 111

```
conditions = [
    ~df.A & ~df.B & ~df.C,
    ~df.A & ~df.B &  df.C,
    ~df.A &  df.B & ~df.C,
    ~df.A &  df.B &  df.C,
     df.A & ~df.B & ~df.C,
     df.A & ~df.B &  df.C,
     df.A &  df.B & ~df.C,
     df.A &  df.B &  df.C,
]

chooses = [
    "",
    "Text3;",
    "Text2;",
    "Text2;Text3;",
    "Text1;",
    "Text1;Text3;",
    "Text1;Text2;",
    "Text1;Text2;Text3;",
]

df["E"] = np.select(conditions,chooses)
```

`df` is the same as above now.

Comment: dude, am yet to understand in entirety but this works like a charm. Thanks for hanging around and getting through!

Comment: would appreciate if you could also share the select 2^3 way too

Comment: @Muds First way is matrix multiplication and we use the fact True is 1 as number and False is 0. I put the second 2^n way with np.select too